# Is it possibile change launch image according to the settings?

Tags: objective-c, ios, image, launch

In the resources of my app project I have Default.png that is my app launch image.

Thanks to the settings bundle, the user can change the start up view, so my problem is finding a way to pick up another launch image if the user changes the settings.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't change files inside your app bundle.

But it's possible to find another easy solution - for this just show a view with the selected Default-Screen after launching your app and then after e.g. 5 seconds show your main view:

```
+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(showMainView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```